# Add GWT Button in AbstractCell

Tags: gwt, button, cell

I am using a AbstractCell to render a specific structure of html and I want to put a GWT button. I need a gwt button with its onclick event but the render function is:

```
public void render(ObjectValue value, Object key, SafeHtmlBuilder sb)
```

and I can not add a gwt button in SafeHtmlBuilder.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
ClickableTextCell recordViewEndorseCell = new ClickableTextCell(){
        @Override
        protected void render(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context,
                SafeHtml value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
            super.render(context, value, sb);
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("<center>Click</center>");
        }   
    };
    recordViewEndorseColumn = new Column<Document, String>(recordViewEndorseCell) {

        @Override
        public String getValue(Document object) {
            return "";
        }
    };
    FieldUpdater<Document, String> summeryUpdater = new FieldUpdater<Document, String>() {

        @Override
        public void update(int index, Document object, String value) { 
            alert("clicked ok");
        }
    };
    recordViewEndorseColumn.setFieldUpdater(summeryUpdater);
```

Comment: I have studied your solution but in this I have to add a column, isn't it? 
I have to wrap all in one cell because I need format it with css style. I have read on internet and I think the best option is use UiBinder to build my cell but the examples are not easy to understand. Do you know how to do it?

Thanks.